# How can I put textfield and graphics in the same jframe?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, textfield

I am trying to have a textfield and graphics in the same jframe but it is not working properly. I want to have the textfield in the bottom and the rest of the jframe for the graphics instead when I run it the textfield acts weirdly and covers up the entire area. Does anybody know how I can get it to work how I want it?

```
package pack;


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class gui extends JPanel implements Runnable{ 

    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    protected JTextField textField;
    private final static String newline = "\n";

    public int x;
    public int y;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new gui();
        new input();
    }

    public void input()
    {
        textField = new JTextField(20);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        c.gridwidth = 500;
        c.gridheight = 100;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(textField, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String text = textField.getText();
        textField.selectAll();
    }

    public gui()
    {
        textField = new JTextField(20);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("lol");
        System.out.println("::");

        f.setTitle("Basic window");
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        f.add(this);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setFocusable(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(textField);

        run();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                t.sleep(10);
            }
            catch(Exception e){}

            System.out.println(":D");
            x++;
            y++;

            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that how your code looks in your editor?

Answer (score 2):

Delete this class and start fresh with a new class. The structure of the code is wrong , the class names are wrong, the custom painting is wrong, the use of Threads is wrong, the `new input()` doesn't do anything, you should not be using Thread.sleep(), you should not override paint(), you should not add a component to the frame after the frame is visible.

Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). There you will find a working example that will show you how to better structure you class when doing custom painting. Use this demo code as the starting point for your program and make changes (one at a time) to this working code.

Then you can change that code and add a JTextField to the frame. You will also need to read the Swing tutorial on `Using Layout Managers`, to understand how a `BorderLayout` works. So start with something simple that works and then add extra components. Don't try to do it all at one time.

Answer (score 1):

Things that you are doing in wrong way.

- `JFrame` by default has uses `BorderLayout` and you are adding two components in the center hence only last components are visible.
- You are adding `JTextField` inside `JFrame` as well as `JPanel`. Don't know why?

---

Use `BorderLayout.SOUTH` to add the `JTextField` in the south and don't add it into `JPanel` as shown below:

```
public gui() {
    ...
    textField = new JTextField(20);
    JFrame f = new JFrame("lol");        
    f.add(this);        
    f.add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    ...
}
```

---

Please read below post once again.

#### [How to Use GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

#### [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)